# std::cin skipped after for loop

Tags: c++

After I input a sequence of numbers (e.g `1 3 4 5` and terminate with `|` or changing the code to break whenever I input `999`, it skips over the following `std::cin` and a 0 appears.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> sequence {};
    std::cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers:\n";
    for (int intBuffer; std::cin >> intBuffer;)
        sequence.push_back(intBuffer);

    int max {};
    std::cout << "When to stop counting?\n";
    std::cin >> max;

    int total {0};
    for (int i=0; i<max; ++i)
        total += sequence[i];

    std::cout << "Total: " << total;
}
```

---

Output:

```
Enter a sequence of numbers:
3 8 4 6 |
When to stop counting?
Total: 0
```

Desired Output:

```
Enter a sequence of numbers:
3 8 4 6 |
When to stop counting?
Total: 21
```

---

I did get this to work by changing the main code to the following, but I do not understand why it works, and it is not intended for the loop to break after inputting a specific integer:

```
for (int intBuffer; std::cin >> intBuffer;) {
    if (intBuffer == 0) break;
    sequence.push_back(intBuffer);
}
```

Comment: When do you expect the `|` to be consumed?

Comment: also, note that your input does not include the number you are expecting to set `max` with